# How to redirect in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am new on Magento. I am facing some problem when open the site in browser.

I am having two sites:

1. http://www.diamondjewelryhub.com
2. http://musicalinstruments101.com/

I have download the `code and database` of http://www.diamondjewelryhub.com. I want to upload  this code and database on the server of http://musicalinstruments101.com/.

After download the data base I searched for this `http://www.diamondjewelryhub.com` and replace with `http://musicalinstruments101.com/`.

After that I have import the database file on the server of `http://musicalinstruments101.com/`, When I am trying to open `http://musicalinstruments101.com/` it redirecting on the site `http://www.diamondjewelryhub.com`.

Is there any change needed because it redirects wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have to change/delete the unsecure_url and secure_url from core_config_data table to be able to access your store on different url

Answer (score 1):

When copying the files onto the new server remember to not copy the contents of `var/` directory. That would include the cache which effectively overrides the database.

Comment: Ya I do the same.Hey can we chat its related to magento

Comment: I am saying this becoz I always noticed when I ask question related to magento you always reply and your answer is really valuable and help me alot

Comment: Gosh! Shucks. ^_^ I'm not used to such compliments. If you need to get in contact the best way will be from [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer/clockworkgeek).

Comment: okbut from here how.Mean what I need to do here to connect with u http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer/clockworkgeek